# Use trigger after multiple insert to update log table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I have the following trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Staging].[tr_UriData_ForInsert]
ON [Staging].[UriData]
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @_Serial NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @_Count AS INT

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @_Count = COUNT(Id) FROM inserted
        SELECT @_Serial = SerialNumber FROM inserted

        INSERT INTO [Staging].[DataLog]
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @_Serial + ': Data Insert --> Rows inserted: ' + @_Count, 'New data has been received')
    END 
END
```

The table receives multiple rows at once. I want to be able to add one row in the log table to tell me the insert has happened.

It works great with one row being inserted, but with multiple rows, the trigger doesn't fire. I have read other items on here and it is quite clear that you shouldn't use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

In summary: I want to update my log table when a multiple row insert happens in another table called UriData.

The data is inserted from C# using the following:

```
using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
            {
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;

                try
                {
                    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
                }
                catch(SqlException sqlEx)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    var msg = sqlEx.Message;
                    return false;

                }
                finally {
                    transaction.Commit();
                    conn.Close();                     
                }
            }
```

I don't want to know what is being inserted, but when it has happened, so I can run a set of SPROCS to clean and pivot the data.

[image: The table looks like the image shown]

TIA

Comment: How do you determine your trigger does not work? And what is the actual statement you use to insert multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of digging and arguing, my hosting company told me that they have disabled bulk inserts of any kind, without bothering to notify their customers.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is your trigger assumes that only one row will be updated. A scalar variable can only have 1 value. So, for example, the statement `SELECT @_Serial = SerialNumber FROM inserted` will set `@_Serial` with the last value returned from the object `inserted`.

Treat your data as what it is, a dataset. This is untested, however, I suspect this gives you the result you want:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Staging].[tr_UriData_ForInsert]
ON [Staging].[UriData]
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

    --No need for a ROWCOUNT. If there are no rows, then nothing was inserted, and this trigger won't happen.

    INSERT INTO [Staging].[DataLog] ({COLUMNS LIST})
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
           SerialNumber + ': Data Insert --> Rows inserted: ' +
           CONVERT(varchar(10),COUNT(SerialNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber)), --COUNT returns an INT, so this statement would have failed with a conversion error too
           'New data has been received'
    FROM inserted;
END
```

Please note my comments or sections in braces (`{}`).

*Edit: Sean, who has since deleted his answer, used `GROUP BY`. I copied what exact method you had, however, `GROUP BY` might well be the clause you want, rather than `OVER`.*

Comment: This. Beat me to it - no insert, no rows, no trigger.

Comment: hehe I hit post before I realized you had already answered nearly identically. :D

Comment: Yeah, I just saw you removed yours @SeanLange (I was probably no more than 3 seconds faster than you), but I thought it was worth noting the difference in regards to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Well I figured there is no point in having two identical answers. Hopefully this is what they want.

Comment: While I am confident this is the correct answer, it doesn't stroke with "but with multiple rows, the trigger doesn't fire". Did OP mean it doesn't fire at all or it fired once and multiple fires were expected?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I ***assumed*** that the OP is misunderstanding, and that they were expecting the trigger to "fire" once per row. Hence they thought that the trigger wasn't firing when there were multiple rows, as it appeared not to (as the values were set to scalar variables). Hopefully the OP will confirm if this is not the case.

Comment: @Larnu Thats a very fair assumption. Although OP seems aware of this, given the use of aggregation and "The table receives multiple rows at once. I want to be able to add one row in the log table". Hopefully OP will respond.

Comment: I admit, @HoneyBadger it's an odd mix. The `COUNT` appears to suggest they are aware that `inserted` will contain multiple rows (as otherwise the value of the `COUNT` would always be 1), but then they have `SELECT @_Serial = SerialNumber FROM inserted`, which suggests the complete opposite. Maybe they were expecting were expecting both; but that makes even less sense.

Comment: @Larnu My thought was they could be *procedurally* certain batch inserts can only occur for a single serial number, and hence didn't care which one would be selected into the variable (I couldn't explain the problem in that case). But this is academic until OP responds. Like I said, you probably got the right end of the stick.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I left it running for a while and nothing appears in the log table. I put a try catch around it to see if there was another error with datatypes, but still, nothing seems to appear. I have put a print statement in there to see if it is firing at all, I know it works with one row. Unfortunately data is sent every 15 minutes so I'll get back shortly.

Comment: As you mentioned, I want to see for which serial number that data came in for. For some background, the data is coming from an API I built which is working fine. So there will be any number of rows coming in for a specific serial number.

Comment: I *assume* you add the column names where I put the braces, @TheOrangeGoblin ?

Comment: Sure did - 'INSERT INTO [Staging].[DataLog] ([TimeStamp],[MessageType],[Message])'

Comment: Nope, nothing happened. I tested it again with one row coming in and it fired. But multiples it failed. The API is adding the data in bulk from a 'db.Add(object)' from C#.

Comment: We need more detail then @TheOrangeGoblin. A trigger will be triggered regardless of if 1 or 1M (or more) rows are inserted. Is the I sent success as well? What is the code used to insert the data (the SQL and application code will likely be useful). What is the definition of the 2 tables? Any constraits, unique indexes? Make sure you add all of this to the question, please don't provide the details in comments (although feel free to mention me once the edit is done).

Comment: From what I am reading, you cant use Bulk insert and triggers, so I will need to change my C#.

Comment: I have changed the insert options to `SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers` and see if that works...